# Get original path capitalization on case-insensitive file system

Tags: php, code-coverage, realpath

A small problem with getting the real directory name for a file. I ran into this while investigating php-code-coverage's code.

On my system running Mac Os I have a structure like this:

```
/project/src/Directory/FileName.php
```

But if I call `realpath()` like this (note directory name case):

```
realpath("project/src/directory/FileName.php")
```

it gives me:

```
<full_name>/project/src/directory/FileName.php
```

So the path is valid for Mac Os, but the directory name is in wrong case, so it is not a "real" realpath.

Is there any way to get a real path with valid cases for such path `"project/src/directory/FileName.php"`? I've tried `pathinfo()` also with no luck.

Comment: did you by any chance changed the directory folder name to Directory after you had already called realpath()? realpath uses cache thats why i am asking.

Comment: Are you using a case-insensitive file system (which is the default)? Then `directory` is just as real as `Directory`. If you can access the file with that path, it's real.

Comment: File system is case-insensitive, as I've written, and that is the problem in this case:) I need not only valid path, but an **exactly** valid path.

Comment: @sietse85 no, no changes.

Comment: "Valid" is the wrong word. It *is* all valid. What you want is the *original* capitalisation. Not sure if there's any way to do that.

Comment: As a hackaround: you could list the entries in the parent directory, which should return them using their original capitalisation; then go through each entry and see if it case-insensitively matches your entry, then use that to replace your entry. That's quite slow and cumbersome to do recursively for each part of the path obviously…

Comment: @deceze Yes, it's too performance consuming. I think about another solution, but it relates to another question: how to find out which system we use - case-sensitive or case-insensitive. It's not actually about OS, but about file systems.

Answer (score -2):

getcwd() can also helps you to find your working directory.

Comment: I'm afraid, it's not what I need.